# What 'final' keyword next to the field stands for?

Tags: spring, kotlin

In a legacy code, I'm working with, I found the following thing:

```
@Autowired
final lateinit var controller: CustomController
```

what does this `final` keyword mean here?

In a Kotlin documentation I found a short description about `final` keyword that is [blocking overriding of the methods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods) in open classes but no information about fields. Also - the class within which I found the line is not open

Comment: Legacy Kotlin code? That’s an oxymoron given the language is so new.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: that was my first thought as well. But according to one definition any code that isn't sufficiently tested is legacy code, so that makes sense ;-)

Comment: By 'legacy' I meant more 'not created by me' than 'ancient' :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `final` property or a method in Kotlin prevents overriding of the field / method. That being said, Kotlin by default considers a property or a method/function to be final unless specified by the keyword `open`. In your case, the final keyword is redundant.

Here's a small demo test case to illustrate the same.

```
open class Parent {
    open val someValue = 0
    final val otherValue = 13 // redundant modifier 'final' warning in Android Studio
}

class Child : Parent() {
    override val someValue = 5
    // override val otherValue = 19 // compile error
}
```

There is an interesting problem called [Fragile Base Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) in OOP and why some languages like Kotlin prefer final by default.

Comment: These are not fields. They are properties. You can’t mark the backing field as open or final.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I agree, I used the term loosely.

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), not a field.

It *looks* just like a field, as it would in Java; but in Kotlin, it actually defines a public getter method, a public setter method, and a private backing field<sup>*</sup>.

So the `final` modifier applies to the accessor methods, preventing *those* from being overridden in a subclass.  (As you say, the backing field itself can't be overridden anyway.)

As Siddharth says, `final` is the default in Kotlin, so you usually wouldn't need to specify it, though there are a few situations in which it would be needed — e.g. if it were already overriding something, or you were using the [all-open](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin) or [kotlin-spring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#spring-support) compiler plug-ins.  (The use of `@Autowired` suggests that this is a Spring module, which probably explains why `final` is needed here.)  In any case, your IDE would probably indicate where it's not needed, e.g. by showing it greyed-out.

<sup>(* Only the getter is necessary; the setter isn't generated for a `val`, and the backing field isn't generated if you override the accessor(s) and they don't refer to it.)</sup>

Comment: Good to know the two plugins mentioned. I was not aware of that!

Comment: "Only the setter is necessary" getter, I assume.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Indeed!  A stupid typo; now fixed, thanks.